# iPad accessible when I connect to internet?

Tags: ios

At one point today my teacher was saying that we shouldn't have social media etc. They also at one point said that the school could access (and view "everything") on our iPads when we are connected to the internet. They did say that the school decided not to do this, but it still bothers me that a network that I connect to has control over my iPad.

So my question is... is this actually possible, can I protect my iPad against this? Can *I* do this? Or is my teacher just trying to make us not do anything bad on our iPads? (Is there something that Apple gave them to get into iPads?)

Comment: Is it your personal device or the school's (or your parents')? Did the school install anything on the device like an app or something?

Comment: It is my device, though when I first signed on, it redirected my to a (local, I think...) website that made me enter a username and password. (Could that have given them access?)

Answer (score 1):

If it's your device, then the short answer is no, you'd have to give them permission. They can view network traffic coming to and from your device, which may be what they're talking about.

Most BYOD management tools  - for example, if you're connecting your iPad to a school or business network and installing specific applications - create a separate partition for the purpose.  The administrator typically has control just over this partition - they can remotely wipe, install, etc - but will have no access to your personal data.